# How to make a post request in angular with/without subscribing?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, angular-httpclient

Imagine that I have a service that fetches some posts from the server.

```js
constructor(private api: APIService) {}
```

So I make a get request like this:

```js
 this.api.getPosts(posts => this.posts = posts);
```

Now if I want to make a post request I would do this inside the component:

```
postNew(post) {
    this.api.postNew(post).subscribe(post => this.posts.push(post))
}
```

My question is the each time I make a post request the above method executes and a new subscriber is created. Which is bad I think. This will occur for other verbs like put, patch and delete. So is there a way around this? I mean to prevent memory leaks.

Do I need to manage subscriptions for each of these methods ? But that will be crazy. Is it ok to pipe a first operator? I'm not sure.

Please suggest a best practice.

Comment: Ok, then why are you not concerned about the `GET` request? Just trying to get a clear context of your question.

Comment: Any help??? Any body..

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default Angular `HttpClient` (which I assume) you don't have to worry about those subscriptions. The returned observable will send a `complete` message to the subscriber after receiving the response data and calling all subscribers. The complete message will automatically unsubscribe all subscribers.

You can check this by providing a `complete` callback to the subscribe function:

```
this.http.get("/assets/test.json")
  .subscribe(
    (data)=>console.log(data),
    (error)=>console.log(error),
    ()=>console.log("complete")
  )
```

Comment: Does the subscriptions close even in the error path?